# How to implement executable and shared library with common code in C

Tags: c, linux, dependencies, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I'm designing a Linux C project which is composed by two binaries: an executable and a shared library.

I have the following project structure using Eclipse-cdt:

```
Main Project Executable
    +-----folderA
        ------------- sourceA.c
        ------------- sourceA.h
    +-----folderB
        ------------- sourceB.c
        ------------- sourceB.h
    main.c

Shared Library Project
    +-----folderB
        ------------- libcode.c
        ------------- libcode.h
```

The Shared Library code in **libcode.c** is strictly dependent on **folderA** and **folderB** code from the Main Project.

How could I organize the projects in order to have no duplicated files?

### Solution A (Current)

The best solution I've found so far, is to use linked resources inside eclipse:

```
Main Project Executable
    +-----folderA
        ------------- sourceA.c
        ------------- sourceA.h
    +-----folderB
        ------------- sourceB.c
        ------------- sourceB.h
        ------------- libcode.c
        ------------- libcode.h
    main.c

Shared Library Project
    +-----folderA [linked]
        ------------- sourceA.c [linked]
        ------------- sourceA.h [linked]
    +-----folderB [linked]
        ------------- sourceB.c [linked]
        ------------- sourceB.h [linked]
        ------------- libcode.c [linked]
        ------------- libcode.h [linked]
```

Notice that I moved 100% of shared library code into the main project and linked all the files I needed in the Shared Library.
This way I don't need to have any "physical" source files inside the Shared Library Project, but I still think it's not a good idea, because it can surprise other developers (violating POLS principle).

### Solution B

There is the option to move all the common code into a third project and make the two projects depend on it, but in my case it will lead into a big code refactoring, which I would like to avoid.

**Any other possibility? Is the solution B definetly a better practice?**

Comment: Why would libcode depend on anything in the main project code? The point of libraries is to be standalone reusable pieces of code, thus able to be linked to ANY project.

Comment: It's a web service implementation, it just extends and serve funcionalities from the main executable, hence the dependency. It must be a shared library in order to be loaded by the http server, and the core is implemented in the main executable.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put the source in `folderA` and `folderB` into your shared library since they apparently contain core functionality. In your executable put the source that uses the library to do something, for example, calling various functions in `libcode` to achieve some goal for the end user. You will need to link the executable to the shared library.

```
Main Project Executable [links to shared library] 
    main.c              [uses libcode to do stuff]

Shared Library Project
    +-----folderA
        ------------- sourceA.c
        ------------- sourceA.h
    +-----folderB
        ------------- sourceB.c
        ------------- sourceB.h
        ------------- libcode.c
        ------------- libcode.h
```

Comment: I'm not sure...there is a lot of stuff from the main project that are not needed to be in the shared library. It's a lightweigth library made just to expose some functionalities from the core and not to be "the core".

Comment: In that case you should go with your solution B above. You were on the right track all along, but I can understand trying to find other options before taking on a bunch of refactoring.